# Service took too long to process intent: com.google.firebase.messaging.NEW_TOKEN App may get closed

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

i added FCM to my app with "intent - filter" added to my android manifest, now when i build my app it gives me this error:

√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Flutter is taking longer than expected to report its views. Still trying...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52135/gEkVmHTO95A=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/OpenGLRenderer( 6155): HWUI GL Pipeline
I/OpenGLRenderer( 6155): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer( 6155): Swap behavior 1
D/        ( 6155): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8c236e00, tid 6217
D/EGL_emulation( 6155): eglCreateContext: 0x9f32d720: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation( 6155): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f32d720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x8c667ff0)
D/        ( 6155): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x90bec8c0, tid 6195
D/EGL_emulation( 6155): eglCreateContext: 0x9f32e080: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation( 6155): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f32e080: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x8e3173b0)
I/Choreographer( 6155): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation( 6155): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f32d720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x8c667ff0)
I/Choreographer( 6155): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/flutter ( 6155): initScreen null
D/AndroidRuntime( 6155): Shutting down VM
I/flutter ( 6155): called INITState of Main()
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155): Process: com.azheennazhad.tamataapp, PID: 6155
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.tamataapp.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.tamataapp.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.azheennazhad.tamataapp-kdADoMkBR58b68DfhVC3lA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.azheennazhad.tamataapp-kdADoMkBR58b68DfhVC3lA==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.azheennazhad.tamataapp-kdADoMkBR58b68DfhVC3lA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3324)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1677)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.tamataapp.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.azheennazhad.tamataapp-kdADoMkBR58b68DfhVC3lA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.azheennazhad.tamataapp-kdADoMkBR58b68DfhVC3lA==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.azheennazhad.tamataapp-kdADoMkBR58b68DfhVC3lA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3321)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6155):    ... 8 more
D/EGL_emulation( 6155): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f32e080: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x8e3173b0)
W/FirebaseInstanceId( 6155): Service took too long to process intent: com.google.firebase.messaging.NEW_TOKEN App may get closed.
Lost connection to device.